# Letting a stranger in safely

Tags: ssh, security, sudo, users

I have setup a really tiny wireguard server in my home, with my public IP and all. I have used NAT to hopefully protect myself as much as possible, set strong passwords... All these things.

A friend wants an ssh access to this server. While he's friendly, i don't want to trust him completely and just give him access, I want to be sure he can't possibly do anything else that messing with his home folder, and never ever run "sudo" or "su".

How can I do this ?

I have tried ChatGPT's advice, and altered visudo like:

```
user ALL=(ALL) ALL, !DISABLE_SU, !DISABLE_SUDO, !/usr/bin/su *,!/usr/bin/sudo *, !/usr/sbin/visudo, !/usr/bin/* *sudoers
```

But when I do `sudo su user` from my session I get "we trust you have received...." and not the expected "you have no rights to run this command" I hoped.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: How do you usually _enable_ `sudo` for a fresh user on your system?  Note that there's nothing stopping you from creating a test user account to play around with.

Comment: why would you believe what chatGPT tells you?

Comment: @jsotola i don't; that's why i'm here :/

Comment: @Kusalananda i don't know, i'm fresh on this. I'd create a user, but the fact that running "sudo" as the new user prompts the spider-man dialogue, i'm worried i may forget something obvious

Comment: That suggestion from ChatGPT is literally insane.  At a glance it appears you are enabling complete access to sudo, except that no user will be able to execute sudo *with* sudo.  Don't ever implement advice from AI without *fully* understanding the implications of what you are doing.  You're lucky you didn't lock yourself out of your own server.

Comment: If your stranger only has specific tasks to fulfil on the server, maybe you want to think about restricted shells or chroot jails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove that `sudoers` line!

You don't need to say that someone can't have access as that's the default. Furthermore you're opening up a major security hole with a trivial attack surface. These commands can be run as your friend in their `user` account:

```
sudo -s
```

Or even this,

```
cp /bin/sh mysh
chmod a+x mysh
sudo ./mysh
```

In either case they now have a root shell.

Also, ensure you haven't added your friend's account to any group that has access rights to run an unrestricted `sudo`. (Typically this would be the `sudo` or `wheel` group.)

---

Incidentally, if you used `visudo` to edit `/etc/sudoers` as you're supposed to, you would (probably) have got the warnings like these:

```
Warning: /etc/sudoers:37:122: Cmnd_Alias "DISABLE_SU" referenced but not defined
Warning: /etc/sudoers:37:122: Cmnd_Alias "DISABLE_SUDO" referenced but not defined
```

Perhaps you did define them, but they're not mentioned in your question. And fixing them won't stop either of the issues described here.

---

You also mention, "*when I do `sudo su user` from my session…*". The `sudo` command without options gives you `root` privileges. Once you're root you then run `su user` which drops you into `user`'s account. If you ran that command from your account you would need your password to enter your friend's account, and its your account that's checked against the rights in the `/etc/sudoers` file. If you ran it from your friend's account then you have given them full rights to `sudo` and could simply run `sudo -s` to get a root shell.

Comment: ahhhhh so it's really because i'm inheriting my root status that i see this ?

Comment: @Orsu I don't quite understand that statement. Your own account has rights to use `sudo`, and the first time you run the command you'll get the default warning message about taking care. Subsequently it will just get on with its job of giving you more privileges. Your friend's account can (could?) also use `sudo` and if you were to log in with their account you would also get the first time warning message there

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to do anything. By default a user does not have `sudo` access, and to use `su` the user needs the root password.

As long as you don't explicitly allow a user to use `sudo`, either by adding them to `sudoers`, or adding them to a group that already has `sudo`-access, they can't use either.